# Insert selected value in extension page on Key press

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created `hot-keys` using Google's `commands` options in the `manifest.json` file.

`manifest.json`:

```
"commands": {
    "name" : {
        "suggested_key": {
             "default": "Alt+N" 
        },
        "description": "Select name"
    },
    "lastname": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Alt+P"
        },
        "description": "Select Last name"
    }
}
```

I want to get **selected text** on press of hot-keys(E.g. `name - Alt+N`) and display it in the `popup.html` page.

I can get the selected text when I click on the extension with the below code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  document.getElementById("product_name").value = selection[0];
});
```

And I can Insert the text in `popup.html` using:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "name") {
         document.getElementById("name").value = SomeValue;
    } else if (command === "lastname") {
         document.getElementById("last_name").value = SomeValue;
     }
});
```

I tried using below code to make both work together:

`popup.js`:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "name") {
         var SomeValue;
         SomeValue = window.getSelection().toString();
         document.getElementById("name").value = SomeValue;
    } else if (command === "lastname") {
         document.getElementById("last_name").value = SomeValue;
     }
});
```

But I get it as undefined. How can I achieve the required output?

Comment: Edit your question and specify to what file each code block belongs. My initial guess is that you're trying to add the listener in a popup script instead of the background/event page js.

Comment: @wOxxOm: I was able to solve the problem but am not sure if it is the ideal solution. Is there a way to implement jquery in extensions?
I am trying to make use of jquery.hotkeys

Comment: jQuery hotkeys won't work on built-in browser pages like Settings or on other extension' pages like chrome-extension://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup page and its script exist only when the popup is shown so you can't add the listeners for browser-global hotkeys there.

Put `chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener` in a [background or event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and use standard communication via [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) between the extension's pages.

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage is something that I used. I wanted to created hotkeys from the extension when the pop-up page is open on the current tab just like in the extension shortcuts.

Comment: the javascript/jquery isn't executing